# Script returning 'TypeError: cannot read property length from NULL' even though its not

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to read in a CSV file with email IDs which will be used as a search filter to get customer records and remove their email ID on their records.

Here is my code

```
var context = nlapiGetContext();
var filedata = nlapiLoadFile(context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript42')).getValue().split(/\n|\n\r/);
for (var i = 0; i < filedata.length; i++) {
  var email = filedata[i];
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'email', email);
  var filters = new Array();
  filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, 'is', email);
  var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, filters, null);
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '# of profiles with this email are:', searchresults.length);
  for (var j = 0; searchresults != null && j < searchresults.length; j++) {
    var id = searchresults[j].getId();
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'cleaning email for: ', id);
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', id);
    record.setFieldValue('email', '');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Result', 'Success');
  }
}
```

I don't see why searchresults is being set to NUll, I tried doing the search through UI to see if its working for that particular email address and its working but not in the script.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try using `nlapiSearchRecord('entity'....` instead of customer.

Customer is the record type, however the search type is `entity`

in the search, add a filter for type is `customer`

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/entity.html

Also, from a governance aspect, you may be better off using `nlapiSubmitField` instead of load/save the customer record.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this one on my console and it worked. Try setting the email variable to a static value for testing to see if it will work. Also, check what is the internal ID of the field where the Email is stored, it is possible that it might be different.

```
var email = "anna_sanchez@bananarama.com"
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'email', email);
var filters = new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, 'is', email);
var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, filters, null);
```